# OpenMPI doesn't send data from an array

Tags: c, openmpi

I am trying to parallelize a grayscale filter for BMP image, my function get stuck when trying to send data from a pixel array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG 1 //tag for messages sent from master to slaves
#define SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG 10 //tag for messages sent from slaves to master

#pragma pack(1)

struct image {
       struct fileHeader fh;
       struct imageHeader ih;
       pixel *array;
};

struct fileHeader {
       //blablabla...      
};

struct imageHeader {
       //blablabla...
};

typedef struct
{
        unsigned char R;
        unsigned char G;
        unsigned char B;
}pixel;


void grayScale_Parallel(struct image *im, int size, int rank)
{
     int i,j,lum,aux,r;
     pixel tmp;

     int total_pixels = (*im).ih.width * (*im).ih.height;
     int qty = total_pixels/(size-1);
     int rest = total_pixels % (size-1);
     MPI_Status status;

     //printf("\n%d\n", rank);

     if(rank == 0)
     {
         for(i=1; i<size; i++){
         j = i*qty - qty;
         aux = j;

         if(rest != 0 && i==size-1) {qty=qty+rest;} //para distrubuir toda la carga
         printf("\nj: %d  qty: %d  rest: %d\n", j, qty, rest);

         //it gets stuck  here,it doesn't send the data
         MPI_Send(&(*im).array[j], qty*3, MPI_BYTE, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         MPI_Send(&aux, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         MPI_Send(&qty, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

         printf("\nSending to node=%d, sender node=%d\n", i, rank);
        }

     }
     else
     {
    MPI_Recv(&aux, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&qty, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

    pixel *arreglo = (pixel *)calloc(qty, sizeof(pixel));
    MPI_Recv(&arreglo[0], qty*3, MPI_BYTE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        //PROCESS RECEIVED PIXELS...
            //SEND to ROOT PROCESS

     }


    if (rank==0){
        //RECEIVE DATA FROM ALL PROCESS
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Status status;

    int op=1;
    char filename_toload[50];
    int bright_number=0;
    struct image image2;

    if (rank==0)
    {
    printf("File to load: \n");
    scanf("%s", filename_toload);
    loadImage(&image2, filename_toload);
    }

    while(op != 0)
    {
        if (rank==0)
        {
        printf("Welcome to example program!\n\n");
        printf("\t1.- GrayScale Parallel Function\n");
        printf("\t2.- Call another Function\n");
        printf("\t0.- Exit\n\t");

        printf("\n\n\tEnter option:");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        }

        //Broadcast the user's choice to all other ranks
        MPI_Bcast(&op, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                    grayScale_Parallel(&image2, size, rank);
                    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    printf("GrayScale applied successfully!\n\n");
                    break;
            case 2:
                    function_blabla();
                    printf("Function called successfully\n\n");
                    break;
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the MPI_Send function can't read the array of pixels, but is strange because i can print the pixels.

Any idea?

Comment: You seem to be hiding pertinent information in your //blablabla from the first else of your grayScale_Parallel function. I see your MPI_Send functions, which are blocking waiting for their MPI_Recv counterpart, which you haven't shown.

Comment: But almost with the above code it should send the data to the ith process.

Comment: MPI_Send is blocking. It will only send when the process is executing MPI_Recv. Asynchronous versions of these functions are MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv. Without your MPI_Recv calls, we can't help you further.

Comment: Ok, i added some additional code for the receiving functions

Comment: If i try to send any other thing than (*im).array[j] it doesn't get stuck, i have the same algorithm implemented without struct image, and i send array[j] and it works pretty good.

Comment: Have you tried to send aux and qty before (*im).array[j] ?

Comment: I sent aux and qyt before (*im).array[j] and now it send data to all process but gets waitinig after `printf("\nSending to node=%d, sender node=%d\n", i, rank);` of the last iteration.

Comment: This seems strange. You should try disabling your compiler optimizations.

Comment: I change the order how i send the data as you told me but for all the send and receive functions and now ir works good, very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate more on Soravux's answer, you should change the order of your `MPI_Send` calls (note the changed `MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG`s) as follows to avoid deadlocks:

```
MPI_Send(&aux, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&qty, 1, MPI_INT, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&(*im).array[j], qty*3, MPI_BYTE, i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

These calls need to be matched by the following sequence of `MPI_Recv` calls

```
MPI_Recv(&aux, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
MPI_Recv(&qty, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

pixel *arreglo = (pixel *)calloc(qty, sizeof(pixel));
MPI_Recv(&arreglo[0], qty*3, MPI_BYTE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I made a simple answer because he fixed his problem with the comment discussion on the question, but your answer is more complete from an external point of view. Have my +1!

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you call `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` is important. You must ensure your calls are always in the same order since these functions are blocking. A call to `MPI_Send` will not return as long as its corresponding (same tag) `MPI_Recv` counterpart is not executed on the destination. This may cause deadlocks otherwise.

Comment: From a learning/debugging point of view, it's important to note that `MPI_Send` *may* block until matched by a corresponding receive, but isn't required to (contrast `MPI_Ssend`). Many implementations will buffer or use an eager protocol for small messages, without waiting for an explicit match. This is good for performance, but can lead people to write formally 'wrong' code that sometimes, even very often, works.